# Parent template argument deduction in nested class constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, inner-classes, template-argument-deduction

I am trying to write the "promotion" constructor of a nested class that can deduce the parent class template. It works fine for the parent class, but not in the nested class. Here is a code example.

```
template <class T>
struct potato {
    struct baked {
        template <class O>
        baked(const typename potato<O>::baked& p)
                : something(static_cast<T>(p.something)) {
        }
        baked() = default;

        T something;
    };

    template <class O>
    potato(const potato<O>& p)
            : mybaked(p.mybaked) {
    }
    potato() = default;

    baked mybaked;
};

int main(int, char**) {
    potato<int> potato1;
    potato<short> potato2(potato1);
}
```

Is this legal?

Various compilers output various errors. Clang has the most readable in my mind. It states :

> candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'O'

https://godbolt.org/z/y_IZiE

So I'm guessing either I've messed up the signature, or this isn't a c++ supported feature.

Comment: FWIW, a copy constructor is never a template function.  The compiler is going to generate a `baked(const baked&)` for you since you didn't.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes that is the desired behavior. Use the "traditional" copy ctor for objects with the same parent class, use the templated one for promotion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to deduce the template argument `T` for a `baked`'s parent `potato<T>`. You can know `T` using `decltype(p.something)` but that doesn't seem to help solve the problem with calling the constructor. One workaround is to change `baked`'s constructor to take any `O` and assume it has a `something` :

```
struct baked {
    template <class O>
    baked(const O & p) : something(static_cast<T>(p.something))
    { }

    baked() = default;

    T something;
};
```

This will work but it is less type-safe than your original code seems to intend. One workaround for *that* problem could be to introduce a `static_assert` that checks that `O` is actually a `potato<U>::baked` :

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct potato {
    struct baked {
        template <class O>
        baked(const O & p) : something(static_cast<T>(p.something))
        {
            using t_parent = potato<decltype(p.something)>;
            static_assert(std::is_same<O, typename t_parent::baked>::value, "Not a baked potato!");
        }

        baked() = default;

        T something;
    };

    template <class O>
    potato(const potato<O>& p)
        : mybaked(p.mybaked) {
    }
    potato() = default;

    baked mybaked;
};
```

This should compile fine for the intended usage but fail with "Not a baked potato!" if you try to pass anything else with a `something`. This would fail :

```
struct foo {
    int something = 0;
};


int main(int, char**) {
    foo bar;
    potato<int>::baked baz(bar); // Error: Not a baked potato!
}
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but just as you say I was hoping to be as type-safe as possible, and also more readable (in my mind). As a last resort, that should certainly do. I'll leave the question open for a little just in case.

Comment: Well, this solution is just as type safe in practice. The problem is that the code is far harder to read than the original code intended to be and that the error message is not very clear. But since this is templated code readable error messages are a luxury. Maybe the fact that it first explicitly says "Not a baked potato!" could be an argument for this solution having a *more* readable error message (or less unreadable). I would be very interested in an answer that actually deduces the template argument. Though if someone does come up with one, it will likely be hard to read as well.

Answer (score 1):

As state by the compiler `O` is not deducible from `const typename potato<O>::baked&` (on left side of `::`).

You have several workarounds:

- Move `baked` outside parent and make it template:

  ```
  // Possibly in namespace details
  template <typename T>
  struct baked_impl {
      template <class O>
      baked_impl(const typename baked_impl<O>& p)
              : something(static_cast<T>(p.something)) {
      }
      baked_impl() = default;

      T something;
  };

  template <class T>
  struct potato {
      using baked = baked_impl<T>;

      // ...
  };
  ```
- Add parent info in `baked` and use SFINAE:

  ```
  template <class T> struct potato;

  // traits for SFINAE
  template <class T> struct is_potato : std::false_type {};
  template <class T> struct is_potato<potato<T>> : std::true_type {};

  template <class T>
  struct potato {
      using value_type = T;
      struct baked {
          using parent = potato;

          template <class O, std::enable_if_t<is_potato<typename O::parent>::value, int> = 0>
          baked(const O& p)
                  : something(static_cast<typename O::parent::value_type>(p.something)) {
          }
          baked() = default;

          T something;
      };
      // ...
  };
  ```